# By which value is this vector being sorted?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

i don't have much clue of C but i want to understand how this code works. My Problem is that i really don't understand how the vector can be sorted in this case. How does it know by which value it has to be sorted?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "LatticeLocation.h"
#include "Body.h"
#include "Region.h"
#include "Particle.h"
#include <queue>

void LatticeLocation::CalculateNeighborhood()
{
        sort(neighborhood.begin(), neighborhood.end());
}
```

Here is the Vector which is sorted:

```
std::vector<LatticeLocation*> neighborhood;
```

And here the LatticeLocation.h file:

```
#pragma once
#include "Point3.h"
#include <vector>

class Summation;
class Body;
class Chunk;
class Region;
class Particle;
class Cell;

class LatticeLocation
{
public:
    Body *body;
    Point3 index;
    Cell *cell;                 // Primarily for rendering... we keep it in the physics engine to make things simple for users

    // Properties
    bool regionExists;          // Set to false if the region is identical to another region or otherwise turned off
    bool edge;                  // Whether this is an edge - i.e., has less than the full number of immediateNeighbors

    // The IMMEDIATE immediateNeighbors
    std::vector<LatticeLocation*> immediateNeighbors;
    LatticeLocation *immediateNeighborsGrid[3][3][3];   // Same as the pointers in the array, just indexed differently

    // Generated
    std::vector<LatticeLocation*> neighborhood;         // All particles up to w links away

    // The elements centered/living here
    Particle *particle;
    Region *region;                         // MAY BE NULL
    std::vector<Summation*> sums[2];        // Sums that live here (not necc. centered). sums[0] = xSums, sums[1] = xySums

    // Used in some algorithms
    unsigned int touch;
    float touchFloat;

    void CalculateNeighborhood();           // Will use a BFS to fill in neighborhood. Also sets regionExists
};
```

stdafx.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#include <math.h>
#include <fvec.h>       // SSE
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <string>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm>
```

All examples of sorting i found use "std:sort" and not just "sort" so maybe it is not the standard sort function which is used here. I searched all the source code files for such a sort function but there is none. Or is it possible that there is a standard sort function which automatically finds out that LatticeLocation contains a sortable Value (Point3 index because Point3 overloads the < operator) and sorts it by that value?

edit:

As it turned out i left some important code out of the above snipped. This should make more sense

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "LatticeLocation.h"
#include "Body.h"
#include "Region.h"
#include "Particle.h"
#include <queue>

    void LatticeLocation::CalculateNeighborhood()
    {
        neighborhood.clear();
        neighborhood = immediateNeighbors;
        sort(neighborhood.begin(), neighborhood.end());
    }
```

Comment: The vector will be sorted via the predicate `std::less<LatticeLocation*>`, which establishes some unspecified, total ordering on pointers. In other words, the resulting order is unspecified.

Comment: C != C++. `std::vector` is not part of C

Comment: Ok that's helping me. I will look deeper into it ^^ Thank you

Comment: To answer your recent edit, it's `std::sort`.  Found through argument-dependent lookup when you pass in `std::vector::iterator` values.

Answer (score 3):

If the vector you are sorting is made up of *pointers* `LatticeLocation*`, then the sort you get is kind of meaningless: you are just sorting pointers (i.e. you are sorting objects based on the particular "random" location they occupy in memory), without considering the *semantics* of your `LatticeLocation` class.

You may want to provide an *ad hoc* custom sorting criteria, using e.g. a *lambda* as the third parameter to `std::sort()`:

```
sort(neighborhood.begin(), neighborhood.end(), [](const LatticeLocation* a, 
                                                  const LatticeLocation* b) {
    // Implement proper code to specify if '*a' is less than '*b'
    .... 
});
```

Comment: There are places for lambdas, but I don't think this is one of them

Comment: @MooingDuck: Why? I think if the OP wants to sort an array of pointers like this, a lambda can make sense (assuming that there is already an `operator<` overload defined for `LatticeLocation`, the lambda's body can be as simple as `return ((*a) < (*b));`. What am I missing here?

Comment: I was merely voicing my opinion that I would prefer an actual function for this over a lambda.  If you use it once, you'll probably want it again, and lambdas decrease readability in many situations. (including this one).

Comment: Well this is not my code i just want to understand it. I guess the one who wrote it knew what he was doing. But i can say that there is no < operator overload defined for LatticeLocation  only for Point3 there is. Sorry if i didn't point that out clearly enough.

Comment: @HyperReud Simple enough.  Add `bool operator<(const LatticeLocation& r) const {return index<r.index;}` to the class.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I recall I read somewhere that a best practice for overloading _binary_ operators like `operator<` was to use _non-member_ functions (possibly `friend` of the class, if they need to access private data in the class), so the OP may want something like: `inline bool operator<(const LatticeLocation& lhs, const LatticeLocation& rhs) { return lhs.index < rhs.index; }`.

Comment: @Mr.C64: In general, yes.  However, that's a little more confusing to novices, and only makes a difference when implicit conversions are involved.  I opted to mention the variant that was more intuitive.

Comment: So if i understand it correct, the pointers are sorted by their location in memory (which i think has much to do with the value of the pointer itself). But then the sorting operation does not seem to make much sense in the end because they point to the Array `LatticeLocation *immediateNeighborsGrid[3][3][3];` which already is kind of sorted.

Comment: I wanted to say they are sorted by the location they **point to** in memory, not the pointers location in memory itself..

Answer (score -1):

It simply compares pointers `LatticeLocation*` according to operator `<`. In fact this code has undefined behaviour if pointers in the vector do not point to elements of some array because you may not compare pointers that do not point to elements of the same array.

For example in the C Standard there is written clear enough

> In all other cases, the behavior is undefined

In the C++ Standard the operator is defined the following way

> 3 Comparing pointers to objects **is defined** as follows: — If two
>   pointers point to different elements of the same array, or to
>   subobjects thereof, the pointer to the element with the higher
>   subscript compares greater. — If one pointer points to an element of
>   an array, or to a subobject thereof, and another pointer points one
>   past the last element of the array, the latter pointer compares
>   greater. — If two pointers point to different non-static data members
>   of the same object, or to subobjects of such members, recursively, the
>   pointer to the later declared member compares greater provided the two
>   members have the same access control (Clause 11) and provided their
>   class is not a union.

In other cases of using pointers the operator is undefined.

Comment: "If two operands p and q compare equal (5.10), p<=q and p>=q both yield true and p<q and p>q both yield
false.  Otherwise, if a pointer p compares greater than a pointer q, p>=q, p>q, q<=p, and q<p all yield true
and p<=q, p<q, q>=p, and q>p all yield false.  Otherwise, the result of each of the operators is unspecified."  That sounds very unspecified to me.

Comment: @Ben Voigt The definition of the operator is given in paragraph #3. Paragraph #4 that you cited does not define the operator for pointers.

Comment: @Vlad: Paragraph number 3 does not define the operator.  It sets up a relationship "pointer compares greater than pointer", which is used in paragraph 4 to define the operators.

Comment: @Ben Voigt I do not understand why you decided that #3 does not define the operator. #4 simply defines the behaviour of operators <= and >= relative to operators < and >. Moreover you may not compare two pointers with operator == if they do not point to elements of the same array or if at least one of them is not null pointer.

Comment: I hope you will sort that out. In the meantime i remove the acception. But it sounded really reasonable though

Comment: @HyperReud  No problem. It is your right. But I am sure that my answer is correct.

Comment: @Vlad: What part of "if a pointer `p` compares greater than a pointer `q`, ... `q<p` yield `true` and ... `p<q` yield `false`" do you interpret as defining `<=` from `<`?

Comment: @Ben Voigt Paragraph #4 does not contain the definition of operator <. It is paragraph #3 that defines the operator. Paragraph #4 simply shows the relationship between operators == <= and <.

Comment: If you two are going to toss paragraph numbers at each other, also communicate the version of the doc.  My copy from Jan 2012 doesn't match _either_ of your descriptions, and I'm not convinced you two are discussing the same version.  5.9/2 of my copy appears to agree with Ben Voight's claim: "If two pointers p and q of the same type point to different objects that are not members of the same object or elements of the same array or to different functions, or if only one of them is null, the results of p<q, p>q, p<=q, and p>=q are unspecified.".

Comment: @Mooing Duck There are some people in the Committee that try to make the Standard more difficult for understanding.:) The words you cited are more clear.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: if it makes you feel better, I thought it was undefined as well until I checked.  _subtraction_ is undefined...

Comment: @MooingDuck: Using n3797 and cross-checked against n3690, both have the new wording I'm citing and Vlad seems also to be using.

Comment: @Vlad: You already said that, but it's not true.  `<` and `>` and `<=` and `>=` are all defined in paragraph 4 (which I cited above in its entirety).  Paragraph 3 contains none of those operators, nor mentions an operator, nor mentions less than.  It just defines what the phrase "a pointer p compares greater than a pointer q", used in paragraph 4, means.  `==` is defined in 5.10p5, but this rule only uses the phrase "compare equal", defined in 5.10p3, not the operator `==`.

Comment: @Ben Voigt I do not agree with you. For example in paragraph #3 there is written: "If two pointers point to different elements of the same array, or to subobjects thereof, the pointer to
the element with the higher subscript compares greater." Take into account the word greater. Moreover in the C standard there is written clear about this. Also I do not understand the words of paragraph #4 "Otherwise, the result of each of the operators is unspecified" Whar is the other case?! Either one pointer is greater than other according to #3 or equal to.

Comment: @Vlad: "compares greater" does not mean `operator >` (yet).  And certainly not `operator <`, which `std::sort` uses.  Paragraph four takes "compares greater" from paragraph 3, and finally connects it to `<`, `>`, `<=`, and `>=`.  And the "otherwise" comes from when none of the paragraph #3 cases applied... which is exactly the scenario discussed here.  Just pretend that paragraph #3 is a function named "compares greater", called in paragraph 4.

Comment: @Vlad: You yourself spoke about the "other cases", in the last sentence of your answer.  And paragraph #4 clearly DOES define what happens in the other case: you get unspecified (i.e. implementation-defined) behavior, not UB.

Comment: @Ben Voigt Thanks Ben. But I do not understant why in C++ this operator has an unspecified result while on C it has undefined behaviour. What is the great idea behind this difference?